# Textual difference between Psukei DeZimra and Psalms 96

Tags: minhag, prayer-book, tehilim-psalms, provenance, pesukei-dezimra

What is the origin of the custom to recite in pesukai dezimra יעלוץ השדה וכל אשר בו instead of יעלוז שדי וכל אשר בו which we are familiar with from Kabbalas Shabbos (psalm 96)?

Answer (score 3):

It's the verse [Ⅰ Chronicles 16:32](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a16.htm#32). The entire passage surrounding that verse in *p'suke d'zimra* is from Chronicles there.